# selected a card, P(not 2 or not 3 or not 4)=?

Tags: probability

It seems like a very simple question but I just cannot figure it out....
Need help from experts~~~

Q: From an ordinary deck of 52 playing cards one is selected at random. Define the following events:

A = card selected is an 2

B = card selected is a 4

C = card selected is a 3

Find

P (not A or not B or not C).

My thought:
P (not A or not B or not C)=1-P(A and B and C).
P(A and B and C)=0 because it is impossible that a randomly selected card could be 4, Ace, and 3 at the same time. Therefore, my answer is 1-0=1. However, the answer is 10/13.

Does anyone know why....?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a problem of colloquial language vs logic language. Clearly "not A or not B or not C" is meant to meant "not A nor B nor C" which in logic is  (not A and not B and not C). Now it's obvious the answer to that is 10/13 I hope. But if you think logically "not A or not B or not C" means "either not A or not B or not C" and as it can't be all three at once it must mean the it must always not be one or not be the other. So the answer 1. Always. But what I dont undestand is why you seem so surprised at the common language answer? Surely it's obvious why the book thinks it.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given, $\frac{10}{13}$, is the answer to **this** question:

What is the probability that the card drawn is neither a $2$, nor a $3$, nor a $4$?

So the person framing the question has used incorrect language to put it on paper, and you have answered the now different question ...correctly.

That's why your answer and the book answer differ...

Answer (score 1):

Your answer looks correct.

Think about this with a Venn diagram. (If you know them, de Morgan's laws come in handy for this problem. Notice that the statement not(A) or not(B) or not(C) is equivalent to not(A and B and C).) If the successful region lies outside of region A or outside of B or outside of C, it just has to lie outside of A, B, and C. We know that P(A and B and C) is 0, as you have mentioned, since we are only drawing one card. Therefore, the correct answer is $\boxed{1}.$ There is nothing wrong with this.